# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Islam Stack Exchange](http://islam.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [The meaning of the hadith: كل راية ترفع قبل قيام القائم ، فصاحبها طاغوت?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/15019/the-meaning-of-the-hadith-%d9%83%d9%84-%d8%b1%d8%a7%d9%8a%d8%a9-%d8%aa%d8%b1%d9%81%d8%b9-%d9%82%d8%a8%d9%84-%d9%82%d9%8a%d8%a7%d9%85-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%82%d8%a7%d8%a6%d9%85-%d9%81%d8%b5%d8%a7%d8%ad%d8%a8%d9%87%d8%a7-%d8%b7%d8%a7%d8%ba%d9%88%d8%aa)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Does eating egg for Sehri makes Roza makrooh?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14937/does-eating-egg-for-sehri-makes-roza-makrooh)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Is Jihad Al-Nikah (جهاد النكاح) an Islamic rule?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/15020/is-jihad-al-nikah-%d8%ac%d9%87%d8%a7%d8%af-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%86%d9%83%d8%a7%d8%ad-an-islamic-rule)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Under what conditions can you break fast after having started it?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16294/under-what-conditions-can-you-break-fast-after-having-started-it)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Zakat on same wealth for every year](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14874/zakat-on-same-wealth-for-every-year)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [I'm 5 weeks pregnant from unlawful relationship, should I abort ?!](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16186/im-5-weeks-pregnant-from-unlawful-relationship-should-i-abort)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Did Adam really commit a sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16541/did-adam-really-commit-a-sin)

**Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

- [What should be the wording of divorce?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16266/what-should-be-the-wording-of-divorce)

**Net Score: -8** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 9)

---

- [How is income taken into account in Zakat calculations](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16235/how-is-income-taken-into-account-in-zakat-calculations)

**Net Score: -8** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 8)

---

- [How should I perform Tasleem when joining late](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16233/how-should-i-perform-tasleem-when-joining-late)

**Net Score: -10** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 10)

---